# coordinates of bounding box in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I want the co-ordinates of the predicted bounding box from tensorflow models.
I am using object-detection script from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb).
After following some answers on stackoverflow I modified the last block of detection as

```
for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
  image = Image.open(image_path)
  # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
  # result image with boxes and labels on it.
  image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
  # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
  image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
  # Actual detection.
  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  width, height = image.size
  print(width,height)
  ymin = output_dict['detection_boxes'][5][0]*height
  xmin = output_dict['detection_boxes'][5][1]*width
  ymax = output_dict['detection_boxes'][5][2]*height
  xmax = output_dict['detection_boxes'][5][3]*width
  #print(output_dict['detection_boxes'][0])
  print (xmin,ymin)
  print (xmax,ymax)
```

However there are 100 tuples in output_dict['detection_boxes'].
There 100 tuples even for those images on whom it failed to predict

What I want is co-ordinates of all the bounding boxes of single image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After expand_dims line you can add these codes. filtered_boxes variable will give bounding boxes whose prediction values are more than 0.5.

```
  (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
      [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
      feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
  indexes = []
  import os
  for i in range (classes.size):
    if(classes[0][i] in range(1,91) and scores[0][i]>0.5):
        indexes.append(i)
  filtered_boxes = boxes[0][indexes, ...]
  filtered_scores = scores[0][indexes, ...]
  filtered_classes = classes[0][indexes, ...]
  filtered_classes = list(set(filtered_classes))
  filtered_classes = [int(i) for i in filtered_classes]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the pipeline.config file of the model you're using, you can see that in some places the maximum number of boxes is set to 100.
For example, in the [config file of ssd_mobilenet_v1](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config), which is the model in the demo notebook you can see it under

```
post_processing {
  batch_non_max_suppression {
    ...
    max_detections_per_class: 100
    max_total_detections: 100
  }
}
```

This is also the default of the input readers (for both train and eval), and you can change them, but this is only relevant in cause you're training/evaluating. In case you want inference without retraining a model, you can simply use a pre-trained model (again, such as ssd_mobilenet_v1), and [exporting](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py) it by yourself while using the `--config_override` argument in order to change the values I mentioned above in the NMS.

Answer (score 0):

```
for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
  image_np = cv2.imread(image_path)
  # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
  image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
  # Actual detection.
  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)

#if using cv2 to load image
(im_width, im_height) = image_np.shape[:2]

ymin = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0][0]*im_height
xmin = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0][1]*im_width
ymax = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0][2]*im_height
xmax = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0][3]*im_width
```

With the above code you will get the desired bounding box coordinates for the class detected with maximum score which is at 0th position indicated by first squared bracket.